# citing with a custom text not numbers or author name (Latex)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, persian

My friend is writing a math thesis in persian language. He wants to cite to references with author names and year both but in persian while the references (at the end of the thesis) are all in English. Is there any way to do this? Please help as I searched and didn't found anything.

This is the command block of his thesis:

```
\usepackage[top=45mm, bottom=45mm, left=45mm, right=45mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{setspace}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false]{hyperref}
\makeindex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}
\linespread{1.50}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Zar}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1.1]{XB Titre}
\defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1.1]{B Traffic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\englishgloss[2]{#2\dotfill\lr{#1}\\}
\newcommand\persiangloss[2]{#1\dotfill\lr{#2}\\}
\renewcommand\proofname{\textbf{برهان}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{مراجع}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{قضیه}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{لم}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{تعریف}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{گزاره}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{نتیجه}[chapter]
\newtheorem{mol}{ملاحظه}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}[chapter]
\newtheorem{nama}{نمادگذاری}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hint}{تذکر}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{توجه}[chapter]
\newtheorem{reminder}{یادآوری}[chapter]
%%%%%%%%%%
%\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}
%\renewcommand{\latinabstract}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\lhead{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\newenvironment{fminipage}%
%{\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}}%
%{\end{minipage}
%\end{Sbox}\fbox{\TheSbox}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{jeld_infomation}
```

Comment: Please tell us which tool (if any) your friend uses to generate the bibliography and the citation call-outs.

Answer (score 3):

Does your friend use BibTeX, biblatex, or another tool to create the bibliography?

If he uses BibTeX and the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/?lang=en) citation management package, he could create "aliases" for the citation call-outs: Use `\defcitealias{key}{<farsi text string>}` to set up the alias, and use `\citetalias{key}` and `\citepalias{key}` to generate citation call-outs using the Farsi text string. Here, `key` is the "key" to a bibliographic entry in question.

---

*Addendum*: Based on your follow-up comment, it would appear that your colleague is building the bibliography by hand, i.e., without a tool such as BibTeX or biblatex. Moreover, as there is no optional argument to the `\bibitem` instruction, the default citation call-out style would appear to be numeric rather than authoryear.

I would like to suggest that your colleague proceed as follows:

- He should load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.
- For each `\bibitem`, provide a `\defcitealias` instruction as shown in the example below.
- To create citation call-outs to these bib entries, use `\citetalias{...}` and `\citepalias{...}` directives.

I'm afraid I don't know how to work with Persian letters. Hence, the following example uses only Latin letters. Hopefully, it'll be clear how to extend the code to a case with Persian letters.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\defcitealias{Atkinson}{SomeLongStringUsingPersianLetters}

\begin{document}

\cite{Atkinson}       % numeric citation call-out

\citetalias{Atkinson} % plain string (no brackets)

\citepalias{Atkinson} % string surrounded by brackets

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Atkinson} Atkinson A.C., (1994). Fast very robust
    methods for the detection of multiple outliers, {\it
    American Statistical Association.} 89, 1329--1339.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mico for your help. Please tell me how do I know which one he is using. I listed all the packages used by him in the preamble of his thesis.

Comment: @Fermat - Is there no `\bibliography` instruction in the body of the paper, and is there no `\bibliographystyle` instruction anywhere in the paper? Incidentally, which document class does your friend use?

Comment: He uses "report" as a documet calss. For the references i see just                                                                     \begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Atkinson}
Atkinson A.C., (1994). Fast very robust methods for the detection of multiple outliers, {\it American Statistical Association.} 89, 1329-1339.
\end{thebibliography}

Comment: Thank you @Mico for your detailed answer. I can not mark the answer as an accepted one since I don't know how to merge my accounts and access to this new account.

Comment: @Fermat - I've posted a query to the site moderators, asking that your accounts be merged.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your method worked fine. But  in the generated PDF file, the two lines containing the alias, for example here,  [SomeLongStringUsingPersianLetters] are hyperlinked with two big green boxes around them.

Comment: @Fermat - Assuming you don't want hyperref to create the hyperlinks, you could either not load the `hyperref` package or load it with the options `colorlinks` and `citecolor=black`.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I resolved the problem. I appreciate you very much.